# How to filter items from drop down list?

Tags: angular

I have an HTML table with data that is displayed (here is an illustration)

[image]

In fact, I would like to create a drop-down list and filter the HTML table according to the "type" column. There are two items in the drop-down list => "IN" or "OUT".

My problem is that when I select "IN" or "OUT", the HTML table does not refresh the page.

If I select "IN" for example, I should retrieve all rows with "IN" (here is an example)

[image]

To come back to my code... The method is called onChangeType()

```js
    public onChangeType(type:any) {
        console.log("Debut ");
     
        this.selectedBrand=type;
            this.filteredCustomer=this.customerTransferts.filter(
              (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
            );
            console.log("Test => ");
            console.log(this.filteredCustomer);     
      }
```

Here are my consoles.logs from my browser.

[image]

I retrieve all the information....

But why is my drop down list not working?

I can share the whole code with you.

TS

```js
    export class CustomerTransfertComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
      customerTransferts: CustomerTransfert[] = [];
      filteredCustomer: CustomerTransfert[]=[];
     
      public selectedBrand: any; 
     
     
      constructor(
        private service: CustomerTransfertService, 
        private modalService: BsModalService)
        { }
     
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCustomerTransfert();
        this.onChangeType;
      }
     
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe$.next();
        this.unsubscribe$.complete();
      }
     
      /* Display datas for the HTML table  */ 
      private getCustomerTransfert(): void {
        this.service.getCustomerTransfert().pipe(
          takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
        ).subscribe(res => {
          console.log("Step 1");
     
          this.customerTransferts = res.PREA.map(val => {
            console.log("Step 2");
            return {
              cler: val.CLER,
              num: val.NUM,
              ref_rbc: val.REF_RBC,
              type: val.TYPE,
              quantite: val.QUANTITE,
              isin: val.ISIN,
              trade_date: val.TRADE_DATE,
              reception_date: val.RECEPTION_DATE,
              statut: val.STATUT,
              label: val.LABEL,
              svm: val.SVM,
              coursMoyenAchat: val.COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT,
              personneContact: val.PERSONNE_CONTACT,
              tel: val.TEL,
              fax: val.FAX,
              date: val.DATE,
              traitementDate: val.TRAITEMENT_DATE,
              annulationDate: val.ANNULATION_DATE,
              intitule1: val.INTITULE1,
              contrepartie: val.CONTREPARTIE,  
              tis: val.TIS   
     
            }
          });
        });
      }
```

```js
    public onChangeType(type:any) {
        console.log("Debut ");
     
        this.selectedBrand=type;
            this.filteredCustomer=this.customerTransferts.filter(
              (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
            );
            console.log("Test => ");
            console.log(this.filteredCustomer);     
      }
     
     
    deleteCustomerTransfert(line: CustomerTransfert): void {
      this.modalService.show(CustomerTransfertCancelConfirmModalComponent, {
        initialState: {
          customerTransfertToCancel: line,
        },
     
        providers: [
     
          { provide: CustomerTransfertService }
     
        ]
     
      });
     
      }
     
    }
```

HTML

```html
    <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
        <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
        <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
    </select>
```

Thank you for your help and your time

**EDIT**

HTML

```
<div class="home-content">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="pt-50">
         <h1 class="text-center pb-3">Consultation des transferts</h1>
         <div class="row pt-3 container">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
                  <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
                  <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="text-end">
                  </div>
                  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                     <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr class="text-center">
                           <th scope="col">Client</th>
                           <th scope="col">N° de préavis</th>
                           <th scope="col">Réf</th>
                           <th scope="col">Type</th>
                           <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
                           <th scope="col">ISIN</th>
                           <th scope="col">Titre</th>
                           <th scope="col">Trade date</th>
                           <th scope="col">Settlement date</th>
                           <th scope="col">Status</th>
                           <th scope="col"></th>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let customerTransfert of customerTransferts">
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.cler}}</td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">
                              <a [routerLink]="['/transferts/customer-transfert-details/' + customerTransfert.num]">{{customerTransfert.num}} </a>
                           </td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.ref_rbc}}</td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.type}}</td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-end">{{customerTransfert.quantite | number:'1.2-2'}}</td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.isin}}</td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.label}}</td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.trade_date | cphFormatDate:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
                           <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.reception_date | cphFormatDate:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
                           <ng-container *ngIf="customerTransfert.statut === 1">
                              <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.statut}}</td>
                              <td class="text-center py-1">
                                 <button (click)="deleteCustomerTransfert(customerTransfert)" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
                              </td>
                           </ng-container>
                           <ng-container *ngIf="customerTransfert.statut === 8">
                              <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.statut}}</td>
                              <td class="text-center py-1">
                              </td>
                           </ng-container>
                           <ng-container *ngIf="customerTransfert.statut === 9">
                              <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.statut}}</td>
                              <td class="text-center py-1">
                              </td>
                           </ng-container>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pb-5"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT2**

```
filteredCustomer: CustomerTransfert[]=[];
```

CutsomerTransfert

```
export interface CustomerTransfert {
    cler: string;
    num: number;
    ref_rbc: string;
    type: string;
    quantite: number;
    isin: string;
    trade_date: Date;
    reception_date: Date;
    statut: number;
    label: string;
    svm: number;
    coursMoyenAchat: number;
    personneContact: string;
    tel: number;
    fax: number;
    date: Date;
    traitementDate: Date,
    annulationDate: Date,
    intitule1: string, 
    contrepartie: string,     
    tis: number,
}
```

JSON file => http://jsonblob.com/961749595051016192

[image]

Comment: Please show the html for your table. ie. how you are linking the array to it. My guess is you have not linked `filteredCustomer` to the table. I can see that array is not instantiated in `ngOnInit` because you forgot brackets on your function call `this.onChangeType;`. So if you had linked the proper array, you would not see any data until the filter had changed. I also don't see any way for `onChangeType()` to return the full array.

Comment: @Chris Hamilton: Thanks for your help, I edited my first post.

Comment: Right so `filteredCustomer` is nowhere to be found in this html.

Comment: @Chris Hamilton: I have to put it where in the HTML (sorry for the question)

Comment: Please see my answer, I've updated it in the past few minutes since I didn't see you initial array was being initialized asynchronously.

Comment: @Chris Hamilton: Yes, I saw your message. Thanks very much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the filtered array in your html

Change:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let customerTransfert of customerTransferts">
```

To:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let customerTransfert of filteredCustomer">
```

Then instantiate `filteredCustomer` in your subscribe callback:

```js
private getCustomerTransfert(): void {
        this.service.getCustomerTransfert().pipe(
          takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
        ).subscribe(res => {
          console.log("Step 1");
     
          this.customerTransferts = res.PREA.map(val => {
            console.log("Step 2");
            return {
              cler: val.CLER,
              num: val.NUM,
              ref_rbc: val.REF_RBC,
              type: val.TYPE,
              quantite: val.QUANTITE,
              isin: val.ISIN,
              trade_date: val.TRADE_DATE,
              reception_date: val.RECEPTION_DATE,
              statut: val.STATUT,
              label: val.LABEL,
              svm: val.SVM,
              coursMoyenAchat: val.COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT,
              personneContact: val.PERSONNE_CONTACT,
              tel: val.TEL,
              fax: val.FAX,
              date: val.DATE,
              traitementDate: val.TRAITEMENT_DATE,
              annulationDate: val.ANNULATION_DATE,
              intitule1: val.INTITULE1,
              contrepartie: val.CONTREPARTIE,  
              tis: val.TIS   
            }
          });
          this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts
        });
}
```

That should do it.

Also, you can remove `this.onChangeType;` from `ngOnInit` as it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !! The filter with `IN` value works!! But, it doesn't work for the `OUT` :-(

Comment: Are you sure the type string is actually `OUT` and not something like `Out` or `out`?

Comment: I think that the problem is now here? `<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
                            <option [value]="'IN'">In</option>
                            <option [value]="'OUT'">Out</option>
                         </select>`

Comment: I can see from your table image that the types are `In` and `Out` not `IN` and `OUT`. You need to change `[value]` to match, or you need to make the filter case insensitive.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot you need to copy the array initially rather than referencing it, change the instantiation to `this.filteredCustomer = [...this.customerTransferts]`

Comment: No Chris, it was working without your last answer. The problem was with me! It works perfectly! I'm happy thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To rehydrate the view you need to work with observables.

So I suggest you to work with pipe async instead of use subscription inside component, so you can skip the unsubscription inside OnDestroy.

Plus, after declaring the observable you can rehydrate it updating the table value inside your onChangeType method.

For sake of semplicity I paste how you could refactoring your ts:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  table$: Observable<any>;

  // ...other vars declarations

  constructor(
    private service: CustomerTransfertService,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.table$ = this.getCustomerTransfert()[0];
  }

  /* Display datas for the HTML table  */
  private getCustomerTransfert(): Observable<void> {
    return this.service.getCustomerTransfert().pipe(
      map((res) =>
        res.PREA.map((val) => ({
          cler: val.CLER,
          num: val.NUM,
          ref_rbc: val.REF_RBC,
          type: val.TYPE,
          quantite: val.QUANTITE,
          isin: val.ISIN,
          trade_date: val.TRADE_DATE,
          reception_date: val.RECEPTION_DATE,
          statut: val.STATUT,
          label: val.LABEL,
          svm: val.SVM,
          coursMoyenAchat: val.COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT,
          personneContact: val.PERSONNE_CONTACT,
          tel: val.TEL,
          fax: val.FAX,
          date: val.DATE,
          traitementDate: val.TRAITEMENT_DATE,
          annulationDate: val.ANNULATION_DATE,
          intitule1: val.INTITULE1,
          contrepartie: val.CONTREPARTIE,
          tis: val.TIS,
        }))
      )
    );
  }

  public onChangeType(type: any) {
    this.table$ =
      type === 'IN'
        ? this.table$.pipe(filter((res) => res.type === 'IN'))
        : this.table$.pipe(filter((res) => res.type === 'OUT'));
  }

  //...other methods
}
```

so in your component html you can render your table like the following:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="table$ | async as table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          table.cler
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          table.num
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
         ecc..
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

I'm not test this snippet but in general way when you need to update your view, this is the approch you need to follow.

Let me know.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.... I have an error message => `TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?   
43       map((res) => ` :-(

Comment: map is a rocks operator you need to import in your TS.

Comment: There is another solution, but thank you for your help.